# Phase shift between pole voltage and line-to-line voltage (3 phase)

Tags: voltage, pwm, inverter, modulation, sine

I understand that the pole voltage phase shift is 120degrees for 3 phase and the line to line voltage is equal to the difference in 2 pole voltages. However, how do I work out the phase shift between a pole voltage (say phase a) and the line to line voltage (vab)?

Thank you.

Comment: Curious: Why do you have _inverter_, _modulation_ and _PWM_ as tags?

Comment: Because the background/area of where my question originated from is for a 3 phase inverter with bipolar sinusoidal PWM modulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**This site**](https://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/tech/threeph.htm) has a nice picture that explains why there is a 30 degrees phase shift between phase and line voltages: -

[image]

For instance, Vca is the addition of Voc and Voa and this produces a phase shift that is 30 degrees lagging to Voa.

If you are not familiar with phasor diagrams then I recommend that you become familiar. It will be time well-spent and it's just half an hour of your life and a few simple lessons in geometry.